# node.js functions returns undefined value

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a problem getting the restaurantname from the db with node.js, it seems it has to do something with callback parameters but I can’t find the solution for my case, hopefully one of you can help me .

I have made function who gets the name of the restaurant from a database. The first console log line gives the right retvalue and the second one gives undefined, how can I write the code so that the return value is the name of the restaurant?

Kind regards, Robert

```
function restaurantName(id) {
  var retvalue;
  try {
    F.model('restaurant').load(id).then(function (restaurant) {
    retvalue = restaurant.Name;
    console.log('restaurantName 1(' + id + ')' + retvalue);
    })
  } catch (err) {
    retvalue = 'Error';
  }
  console.log('restaurantName 2(' + id + ')' + retvalue);
  return retvalue;
};
```

Comment: Can't you keep the second `console.log` inside the `try` block?

Comment: You're not handling any error case in your callback function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function getting data from database is asynchronous, so the second `console.log` as well as `return` statement are done before the database operation finishes executing. You should return the value inside `.then()`

```
function restaurantName(id) {
    var retvalue;

    return F.model('restaurant').load(id).then(function (restaurant) {
        retvalue = restaurant.Name;
        console.log('restaurantName 1(' + id + ')' + retvalue);   
        return retvalue;           
    }).catch(function(error){
        return 'Error';
    });
};
```

And this function will also return a [**`promise`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you would have to call it like that

```
restaurantName(1).then(function(result){
    console.log(result); // result would be retValue or 'Error'
});
```

**EDIT**

Your second problem, mentioned in a comment below this answer, is also concerned with how the promises work. In this case I recommend you use [**`Promise.all`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method which resolves when all of the promises passed as an argument will resolve

```
let promises = [];
snapshot.forEach(u => {
    let item = u.val();
    item.key = u.key;

    promises.push(restaurantName(item.restaurant).then(function(result){
        item.restaurantName = result;
        return item;
    }));
});

Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
    console.log(result); // here you get array of items 
});
```

What happens here is you create an array of promises that resolve with given value (which in this case is `item` object every time). When you pass this array to `Promise.all` method, it resolves to array of values that every single promise resolved to (if no error occurs of course)

Comment: The original function call is: item.restaurantName = restaurantName(item.restaurant);
I've replaced it with: 
  restaurantName(item.restaurant).then(function (result) {
     console.log('result: ' + result); // result would be retValue or 'Error'
     item.restaurantName = result;          
  });    
  
  The result of the call is Error in stead of the correct name (which is returned in the function)

Comment: So you have to do `restaurantName(item.restaurant).then(function(result){ item.restaurantName = result; });`

Comment: There was a typo in my answer, there was `return retValue` whereas it should be `return retvalue`, maybe that's the case if you got the same code as in my answer

Comment: Now the function returns the correct name and when I use it in the call it is working fine in the log(22), but before the push the variable is undefined again, do you have a solution for that?

snapshot.forEach(u => {
      let item = u.val();
      item.key = u.key;

      restaurantName(item.restaurant).then(function (result) {
        item.restaurantName = result;
        console.log('22 user:' + item.name + ' ' + item.restaurantName);
      });
      console.log('24 user:' + item.name + ' ' + item.restaurantName);
      sorted.push(item);
   });

Comment: It is another issue related to how the [**`promises`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) work. You need to read about them and understand at least their basic concepts, otherwise you will constantly encounter similar problems. Also, read about **`asynchronous`** operations in javascript

Comment: I'm really gone do that! is it easy to passback the item.restaurantName value? in this block?

Comment: You helped me a lot, is it possible that you help me with the last part?

Comment: I edited the answer to include solution of this problem

Comment: the result now contains the correct value restaurantname, but I don't know how to handle the sort event: sorted.push(item);

Comment: I think there is one thing missing, right now there is no result on the page, I think it has to do with the sorted method, whereever I place it I don't get the results

Comment: Right now, the sort function outside the promises doesn't have the restaurantname information, where do I have to place the call: sorted.push(item);